# Pandas - make a column dtype object or Factor

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, how can I convert a column of a DataFrame into dtype object?
Or better yet, into a factor? (For those who speak R, in Python, how do I `as.factor()`?)

Also, what's the difference between `pandas.Factor` and `pandas.Categorical`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use the [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) method to cast a Series (one column):

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].astype(object)
```

Or the entire DataFrame:

```
df = df.astype(object)
```

---

#### Update

[Since version 0.15, you can use the category datatype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) in a Series/column:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].astype('category')
```

*Note: `pd.Factor` was been deprecated and has been removed in favor of `pd.Categorical`.*

Comment: Thank you soo much, that was becoming a massive headache.

Comment: When Trying this I am getting "TypeError: data type not understood"  I am trying this with both data['engagement'] = data['engagement'].astype(data)
AND data = data.astype(data). My column is engagement          5000 non-null float64

Comment: You need to use object? `data['engagement'].astype(object)`... If they are already floats why would you want to change to object?

Comment: Note: Also that when this original answer was written creating a categorical then setting it to a column, the column was converted to object (or another dtype), as you couldn't (until 0.15) have categorical columns/Series.

Answer (score 17):

There's also pd.factorize function to use:

```
# use the df data from @herrfz

In [150]: pd.factorize(df.b)
Out[150]: (array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2]), array(['yes', 'no', 'absent'], dtype=object))
In [152]: df['c'] = pd.factorize(df.b)[0]

In [153]: df
Out[153]: 
   a       b  c
0  1     yes  0
1  2      no  1
2  3     yes  0
3  4      no  1
4  5  absent  2
```

Answer (score 12):

`Factor` and `Categorical` are the same, as far as I know. I think it was initially called Factor, and then changed to Categorical. To convert to Categorical maybe you can use `pandas.Categorical.from_array`, something like this:

```
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b' : ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'absent']})

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
   a       b
0  1     yes
1  2      no
2  3     yes
3  4      no
4  5  absent

In [29]: df['c'] = pd.Categorical.from_array(df.b).labels

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
   a       b  c
0  1     yes  2
1  2      no  1
2  3     yes  2
3  4      no  1
4  5  absent  0
```

Comment: be noted that above usage have been deprecated, and need to use as below:   `pd.Categorical(df.b).codes`