# Find frequency of combinations of values in pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I've got three project categories `A, B and C` that can have three different statuses `Started, Finished and canceled`. I'm trying to find the percentage of categories that have for example `Status = Finished` for all categories. I think the first step should be to display it in a matrix like below:

**Input:**

```
Category Status
A Started
A Started
A Finished
A Finished
B Started
B Canceled
B Canceled
C Started
C Finished
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    Started Finished Canceled
A   2       2        0
B   1       0        2
C   1       1        0
```

But I'm struggling to identify the possible statuses that for example A *can* have, but *does not*. In this example `Canceled = 0`. I've been trying to do this by subsetting a pandas dataframe by unique observations for `Category`, and then joining them to fill non-existent combinations with `nan`. But I think this would be *very slow* for bigger datesets. Also, I'm not quite there yet. Here's the code if anyone would like to try and build on it. But I'm suspecting that there's a much more efficient solution out there somewhere...

**My attempt:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s+')
# dft = df.T
frames = {}
n = 0

status = df['Status'].unique()

# Subset and create dataframes
for category in df['Category'].unique():
    n = n + 1
    newname = 'df_' + str(n)
    print(newname)
    dfs = df[df['Category']==category]
    frames[newname] = dfs

# Join dataframes
df_main = frames['df_1']
frames.pop('df_1')


for key in frames:
    df_main = pd.merge(df_main, frames[key], on = 'Category', how = 'outer')

df_main = df_main.set_index(['Category'])
df_main.columns = status
```

**Output df_main:**

```
          Started  Finished  Canceled
Category                              
A          Started       NaN       NaN
A          Started       NaN       NaN
A         Finished       NaN       NaN
A         Finished       NaN       NaN
B              NaN   Started       NaN
B              NaN  Canceled       NaN
B              NaN  Canceled       NaN
C              NaN       NaN   Started
C              NaN       NaN  Finished
```

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab(df.Category, df.Status)`?

Comment: I looking for better dupe and add it, now it is better?

Comment: And so sorry for not 100% matched dupe before.

Comment: Your conlcusion was correct from the beginning. I removed my edit because I for a second messed up the links and though that the link below was the duplicate. My mistake 100%. Sorry. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307301/pandas-replacing-column-values-in-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1