# how to replace variables in a column

Tags: python, pandas

i wanted to to replace the yes and no values in No-show column to be changed to 0 and 1 values[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQklg.png)

Comment: Hi, perhaps use `DataFrame.replace` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing column values in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307301/replacing-column-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'No-show':['Yes','No','No','Yes']})
df['No-show'] = df['No-show'].replace('Yes',1).replace('No',0)
df
```

output:

```
    No-show
0   1
1   0
2   0
3   1
```

Comment: Series.replace also accepts a dictionary so you don't need to call it twice: `df['No-show'] = df['No-show'].replace({"Yes": 1, "No": 0})`