# Date replacement Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, replace

I am stuck on an probably stupid issue but I can't find a way.

In my dataframe I have some dates.
I want to replace '3000-01-01' by '2900-01-01'.
I tried with simple quotes:

```
BAB = BAB.replace('3000-01-01','2900-01-01')
```

double quotes:

```
BAB = BAB.replace("3000-01-01","2900-01-01")
```

and also by filtering

```
BAB[BAB['ADHEND'] == '3000-01-01'] = '2900-01-01'
```

but not working, like the screenshot shows

[image]

Can someone helps me understand why?

Thanks

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632) and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing column values in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307301/replacing-column-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks @buran, it gave me another idea: "BAB.loc[BAB.ADHEND == '3000-01-01', 'ADHEND'] = '2900-01-01'" but it still doesn't work

Comment: Try: `df.replace('\s*3000-01-01\s*', '2900-01-01', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

If `BAB.replace('\s*3000-01-01\s*', '2900-01-01', regex=True)` doesn't work, it's probably because each value is an instance of `date`:

```
>>> BBA.loc[493704, 'ADHEND']
datetime.date(3000, 1, 1)
```

If you have the output above, try:

```
from datetime import date

df.loc[df['ADHEND'] == date(3000, 1, 1), 'ADHEND'] = date(2900, 1, 1)
```