# Replacing < containing values in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and in some columns there are values such as "<0.5, <10, <100" etc. I want to replace all those values with 0 if the value just contains "<". How can I do it? I'm relatively new with Python.

Tried to use pd.DataFrame.replace().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing column values in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307301/replacing-column-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Please be explicit, provide a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464). If you just want to replace a literal `'<'`: `df.replace('<', 0)`

Comment: You want all values containing < to be replaced with zero?

Comment: @MrIrrelevant yes, I want all values containing < to be replaced with zero

Comment: Why are you not providing samples as suggested by @mozway? Why are you not responding to requests?

Comment: @mozway sorry, new to this platform and didn't notice all comments. Solved now though and can't provide more specified sample due to work.

Comment: @PandaKim sorry, new to this platform and didn't notice all comments. Solved now though and can't provide more specified sample due to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df["Column"].str.contains("<",na=False)]=0
```

Comment: Thank you! Had only to add `na=False` there

Comment: And post your final code so that we can edit the answer

Answer (score 2):

Solved, final code snippet `df[df["Column"].str.contains("<",na=False)]=0`