# How to label each group with df.groupby() in Python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Note: this question can be associated with one existing question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723628/pandas-make-a-column-dtype-object-or-factor). However, my question provides a more concrete example and has broader impact.

Consider we have a pandas data frame as following:

```
   Questions  cnt similarity
0       ABC    1  [1, 2, 3]
1       abc    2  [1, 2, 3]
2       cba    3  [2, 3, 1]
3      abcd    4  [4, 5, 6]
4      dcsa    5  [2, 3, 1]
5      adcd    6  [4, 5, 6]
6      abcd    7  [1, 2, 3]
7       cba    8  [7, 8, 9]
```

I have to add another column called `cat` based on the `similarity` column. If two rows have the same `similarity`, then categorize them as the same group. Below is the expected output. Any input is valuable. It is worth mentioning that the original dataset has `1M` rows. Thank you.

```
  Questions  cnt similarity  cat
0       ABC    1  [1, 2, 3]    1
1       abc    2  [1, 2, 3]    1
2       cba    3  [2, 3, 1]    2
3      abcd    4  [4, 5, 6]    3
4      dcsa    5  [2, 3, 1]    2
5      adcd    6  [4, 5, 6]    3
6      abcd    7  [1, 2, 3]    1
7       cba    8  [7, 8, 9]    4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) :

```
df["cat"] = pd.factorize(df["similarity"].astype(str))[0] + 1
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

  Questions  cnt similarity  cat
0       ABC    1  [1, 2, 3]    1
1       abc    2  [1, 2, 3]    1
2       cba    3  [2, 3, 1]    2
3      abcd    4  [4, 5, 6]    3
4      dcsa    5  [2, 3, 1]    2
5      adcd    6  [4, 5, 6]    3
6      abcd    7  [1, 2, 3]    1
7       cba    8  [7, 8, 9]    4
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `groupby.ngroup()`:

```
df['cat'] = df.groupby('similarity').ngroup()+1
```

```
  Questions  cnt similarity  cat
0       ABC    1  [1, 2, 3]    1
1       abc    2  [1, 2, 3]    1
2       cba    3  [2, 3, 1]    2
3      abcd    4  [4, 5, 6]    3
4      dcsa    5  [2, 3, 1]    2
5      adcd    6  [4, 5, 6]    3
6      abcd    7  [1, 2, 3]    1
7       cba    8  [7, 8, 9]    4
```